# Python Upload Photo To Album with Facebook's Graph API

Tags: python, facebook

I've seen this post
[Upload Photo To Album with Facebook's Graph API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2718610/upload-photo-to-album-with-facebooks-graph-api)
I want to know whether this is possible with python?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do with any language as long you can `HTTP POST` the data to the endpoint. The API itself is independent of the language you use to access it.

Example: [facepy](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy)

```
graph = GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)
graph.post(
    path = 'ALBUM_ID/photos',
    source = open('parrot.jpg')
)
```

See more at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/#photos

Comment: hey thanks ...
can u tell me/suggest where i can find docs for the fb-py sdk.
The docs of fb are explained using php.

Comment: @AjayKumar https://facepy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/graph-api.html and there are a few blogs out there that use it in examples including mine http://philippeharewood.com/facebook/tag/facepy/